# GKE auto-upgrade at the v1.23 end-of-life did not upgrade to v1.24 but v1.23 again?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Today was the last day of life for GKE v1.23, as I removed upgrade maintenance exclusion the upgrade automatically started and went through 11 nodes of mine in 3 hours. After re-deploying all the workloads the GKE version is still v1.23 and there is no more notification in the cluster details stating that an upgrade is scheduled for the cluster! What has happened? what should I do/expect?

I expected the cluster to be upgraded to v1.24, as my other clusters did!

Answer (score 0):

Are your cluster updated mananged by Google itself , what is the upgrade type that you have selected for the cluster.

you can use cloud logging to check if there are any events related to upgrade

```
resource.type="gke_cluster"
protoPayload.metadata.operationType=~"(UPDATE_CLUSTER|UPGRADE_MASTER)"
resource.labels.cluster_name="CLUSTER_NAME"
```

you can check this query to see if any update has happened,

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-upgrades for more details.

Also it is better to keep a maintainence window so that there won't be any disruptions.